# Image upload working in localhost but not in IIS server [ Asp.net Mvc ]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost, iis-8

I am working on a MVC project where I am trying to upload an image through ajax; This is absolutely working fine on localhost, however it does not work on IIS web server. Once i pressed submit button, it shows error on console, saying :

## "http://blahblahmywebsite.com/UserRegistration/UserPhoto 500 (Internal Server Error)".

I am struggling with this issue for 2 days now, Any suggestion?

N.B.

-> I have tried already : url: '@Url.Action("FunctionName", "Controller")'

-> Manipulation in  application pool (suggested by other online posts)

->I have hosted this site on godaddy server which is using IIS 8.

->I am using .NET 4.5.2 for local server

This is my jQuery:

```
     $("#fileUserImage").change(function () {
        userImage();
    });

    function userImage() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileUserImage").files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
            var file = document.getElementById("fileUserImage").files[i];
            formData.append("fileUserImage", file);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/UserRegistration/UserPhoto',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (image) {
                $("#imgUserImage").attr('src', '../' + image);

                alert("Entered into success block");

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("Entered into error block");
            }
        });
    }
```

This is my Html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-5 control-label">Photo</label>
         <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="file" id="fileUserImage" name="fileUserImage">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="img-wrap col-md-offset-5">
            <img class="example-image" id="imgUserImage" width="220" style="padding-left:17px;" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UserPhoto()
    {
        var userPic = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[i];

            if (file != null)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/User/"), DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Year + fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                userPic = "Images/User/" + DateTime.Now.Day + "" + DateTime.Now.Month + "" + DateTime.Now.Year + fileName;
            }
            else
            {
                userPic = "";
            }
        }
        return Json(userPic, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: The absolute very first thing you always got to do on a 500 Internal Server Error, is go check the relevant error logs. (If you don’t have access, ask support.)

Comment: IT SAYS:
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: _“The current custom error settings for this application prevent [...]”_ – well then I’d suggest you first of all change those settings.

Comment: Finally, I got the solution. 
The only thing I had to do is to give the permission to the Folder(s) where the images are going to be saved. Now, everything is working as expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check Your Destination Folder --> Right Click the folder --> Properties --> Security Tab --> Edit Button--> Allow the Security. See the image below. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: You are Welcome !

Comment: what if the image is read it as  Byte[] bytes, I have the same issue  but Im not storing the files on the server, instead I convert the picture in a byte array and then I store it in the database as img type, but when I deploy on the iis v 7.5 is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

I hosted my website on a remote server and had the same issue. Later on I found that application users did not have add/edit permission for images folder.